# C# BindingSource with DateTime Field-value with different format then Db not able to save

Tags: c#, data-binding, datetime-format

I have some datefields in my datasource I would like to format these dates in a textbox on screen in a different format then they are stored in the db. I also want the user to be able to change the date in this format. But this is not possible. The textboxes won't accept the inputed date.

For formatting in the textbox I use:

```
tbSysDateFrom.DataBindings.Add("Text", myBindingSource, "SysDateFrom", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, "", "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

This works. But when the user tries to enter a date, i.e. 23-12-2015 the textbox won't accept it. I can understand this because in the database the format is MM/dd/yyyy in this example the datasource thinks that 23 is a month value.

The same problem I have with presenting the data in a GridView. I can format the date to dd-MM-yyyy, but the user is forced to enter the date in a format like MM-dd-yyyy

I'm not sure how to solve this, so does anybody have an idea. Maybe overwriting some methods? But which ones and when? Can anyone put me in the right direction?

B.t.w. I have to use textboxes (cannot use a datepicker)

**[Update]**

Ok, I was able to figure out how to solve this issue for a textbox. I did this by adding a validation event for the textbox using this code:

```
 private void tbSysDateTo_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dateValue;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSysDateTo.Text))
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(tbSysDateTo.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
                tbSysDateTo.Text = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dateValue);
        }
    }
```

This works, now I have to do the same for the gridview. Here I'm still stuck. When I change the format in the CellValidating event, I get an error on when the bindingsource wants to save the date.

The error is related to the date: "String was nog recognized as a valid DateTime".

Any suggestions how to solve this issue? TIA

Comment: so what's stopping you from reformatting the String Date to the correct format before storing it in the database..? also on the GridView what is the DataFormatString that you are using in regards to displaying can you show that as well

Comment: Hi MethodMan, same formating: dd-MM-yyyy. I do understand what you say. But my question is how and where (which event should I use to reformat it) so it can be stored and the validation won't prevent going to the next field.

Comment: without seeing your existing code I can't for certainty tell you where to put it.. can you post your existing code..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, I was able to solve my issues. First the TextBox-issue (BTW all controle are bound using BindingSources):

The TextBox had to be formatted as dd-MM-yyyy. To do this I added binding tot the TextBox like this

```
tbSysDateTo.DataBindings.Add("Text", myBindingSource, "SysDateTo", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, "", "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

This works fine, but when I tried to save the date, an exception was thrown because of the wrong format. I was able to solve this by reformat the text of the TextBox in the validating-event of this TextBox, like:

```
private void tbSysDateTo_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dateValue;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSysDateTo.Text))
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(tbSysDateTo.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
            tbSysDateTo.Text = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dateValue);
    }
}
```

As for the GridView, where also datefields are shown formatted as dd-MM-yyyy, I had to do something similar. But I didn't know which event to use. Row_Validation or Cell_validation didn't do the trick.

I ended up using the CellParsing event which is working fine for me.

```
 private void dgv_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dateValue;

        // Confirm that the cell is not empty.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value.ToString()))
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Value.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
            {
                e.Value = dateValue;
                e.ParsingApplied = true;                
            }
        }
    }
```

See: [This For More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellparsing?view=netframework-4.8)

(corrected the link in More Info, because MS obviously moved the content again)